# Incorrect datetime error on unrelated field when creating an index

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I've got a database with locations table which contains string fields representing address of given location - first line, postcode, city (the table is using `timestamps` and `softDeletes`). I'm now creating a cities table, where give location will be connected to city by a foreign key.

The schema for this migration is represented as such:

```
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::table('locations', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
});
```

Unfortunately this gives me following error:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'deleted_
  at' at row 154 (SQL: alter table `locations` add constraint `locations_city_id_foreign` foreign key (`city_id`) ref
  erences `cities` (`id`))
```

Now, there's an easy way to fix this, by running following between create cities table and creation of index:

```
DB::table('locations')->where('deleted_at', "0000-00-00 00:00:00")->update([
    'deleted_at' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

The question is - why creation of index on unrelated column checks a value on  deleted_at?

---

Per comments here's current output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE locations`:

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `external_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_pickup_choice` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `address_line_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `address_line_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `town` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `postcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `longitude` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `latitude` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `type_of_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_pickup` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `is_dropoff` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `is_live` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `is_actual_point` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_near_public_transport` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `public_transport_notes` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `notes` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_fictional` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `city_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `locations_latitude_index` (`latitude`),
 KEY `locations_longitude_index` (`longitude`),
 KEY `locations_deleted_at_index` (`deleted_at`),
 KEY `locations_city_id_foreign` (`city_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `locations_city_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8440 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Is this all done in a single migration file?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: What does your migration look like for the locations table?

Comment: Added `SHOW CREATE TABLE`